# NodeJS can't install it properly

Tags: node.js

I had problem with create-react-app and turned out I gotta update my version of nodeJS. The thing is that I can't do so. when I type node --version I get v11.10.0, however when I type sudo n stable, I get:installed : v10.16.3 (with npm 6.9.0).
However when checking version of node I all time get this 11.10.0. How can I get this last stable version 10.16.3?

EDIT: SOLVED
turned out nvm was installed on laptop and it controled node version

Comment: which os you are using?

Comment: @krishnasapkal I use Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: I has a similar issue when I updated my node version, uninstalling all of them and then reinstalling the wanted one solved the problem for me.

Comment: @Lumpenstein, and how to uninstall it? As I tried ```sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs``` and eventho in theory it was removed, then again after typing node --version I get this v11.10.0

Comment: why don't accept any one of the below answer so the people will know the solution?

Comment: @Jacki sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs (purge for removing, --auto-remove removes dependancies that are no longer needed).
Edit: Sorry didn't read the end of your comment, that you tried this already. Maybe try this https://askubuntu.com/a/992859

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use nvm to manage your node versions. It allows you to download multiple versions and you can assign versions on a per project basis. It also allows you to choose which version you want as default

Answer (score 1):

Install nvm it will allow you to install and use any version you want.
[Installation steps](https://gist.github.com/tomsihap/e703b9b063ecc101f5a4fc0b01a514c9) on ubuntu 18.04